# Capturar atributos de uma Imagem com JavaScript ou JQuery através da Url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho uma imagem que vai ser renderizada em uma Div, porem preciso capturar o Height dela pois preciso tratar antes de colocar ela no div (tamanho).
Não tenho a imagem na tela, por isso não consigo fazer um document.GetElement..

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse link, pode ser útil, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575159/get-image-dimensions-with-javascript-before-image-has-fully-loaded

Comment: Opa! Valeu , foi bem perto que o Guilherme postou aqui abaixo.. e deu certo! Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a função abaixo

```
var tmpImg = new Image();
tmpImg.src="https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"; //or  document.images[i].src;
$(tmpImg).one('load',function(){
 orgWidth = tmpImg.width;
 orgHeight = tmpImg.height;
 alert(orgWidth+"x"+orgHeight);
});
```